# Get data from php to JavaScript [validation email]

Tags: javascript, php, html, validation, email-validation

How can I get data from PHP to Javascript ?
I hava an error message generated by a PHP script, and I want to get the message into JavaScript to display the results of email validation.

I finished the error validation script for the case when the input form is empty,
 and now I am confused about how to get a success message if the input form is not empty and email validation is successful.

Can anybody help me ?

This is my PHP Code:

```
{"error":1,"info":[
{"fieldId":"contact-form-name","message":"Please enter your name."},
{"fieldId":"contact-form-mail","message":"Please enter valid e-mail."},
{"fieldId":"contact-form-message","message":"Please enter your message."}]}
```

and this is my JavaScript code :

```
;(function($,doc,win) {
"use strict";

var contactForm=function(object,option)
{
    /**********************************************************************/

    var $self=this;
    var $this=$(object);
    var $option=option;

    /**********************************************************************/

    this.build=function() 
    {
        $this.bind('submit',function(e) 
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            $self.submit();
        });
    };

    /**********************************************************************/

    this.submit=function()
    {
        this.blockForm(true);
        <!--$.post('plugin/contact-form/contact-form.php',$this.serialize(),this.processResponse,'json');-->            
        $.post('plugin/contact-form/contact-form.php',$this.serialize(),this.processResponse,'json');           
    };

    /**********************************************************************/

    this.processResponse=function(response)
    {
        $self.blockForm(false);
        $this.find('li').qtip('destroy');

        var error=false;

        if(typeof(response.info)!='undefined')
        {   
            if(response.info.length)
            {   
                for(var key in response.info)
                {
                    error=error || response.error;

                    $('#'+response.info[key].fieldId).parents('li:first').qtip(
                    {
                        show        :   
                        { 
                            target  :   $(this) 
                        },
                        style       :   
                        { 
                            classes :   (response.error==1 ? 'template-qtip template-qtip-error' : 'template-qtip template-qtip-success')
                        },
                        content     :   
                        { 
                            text    :   response.info[key].message 
                        },
                        position    :   
                        { 
                            my      :   'bottom center',
                            at      :   'top center' 
                        }
                    }).qtip('show');    
                }
            }
        }

        if(!error) 
        {
            $this.find('input[type="text"],textarea').val('').blur();
            window.setTimeout(function() 
            { 
                $('#contact-form-submit').qtip('destroy'); 
            },2000);
        }           
    };

    /**********************************************************************/

    this.blockForm=function(block)
    {
        if(block) $this.find('li').block({message:false,overlayCSS:{opacity:'0.3'}});
        else $this.find('li').unblock();            
    };

    /**********************************************************************/
}

/**************************************************************************/

$.fn.contactForm=function(option) 
{
    return this.each(function() 
    {
        var object=new contactForm(this,option);
        object.build();

        return(object);
    });
};

})(jQuery,document,window);
```

and this is my form :

```
<form name="contact-form" id="contact-form" method="post">

                    <ul class="template-reset-list template-clear-fix">

                        <li>
                            <label for="contact-form-name" class="template-infield">Name (required)</label>
                            <input type="text" name="contact-form-name" id="contact-form-name"/>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label for="contact-form-mail" class="template-infield">E-mail (required)</label>
                            <input type="text" name="contact-form-mail" id="contact-form-mail"/>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label for="contact-form-website" class="template-infield">Websiste</label>
                            <input type="text" name="contact-form-website" id="contact-form-website"/>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label for="contact-form-subject" class="template-infield">Subject</label>
                            <input type="text" name="contact-form-subject" id="contact-form-subject"/>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label for="contact-form-message" class="template-infield">Message (required)</label>
                            <textarea name="contact-form-message" id="contact-form-message"></textarea>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label for="contact-form-submit" class="template-infield"></label>
                            <input type="submit" name="contact-form-submit" id="contact-form-submit" value="Submit"/>
                        </li>

                    </ul>

                </form>
```

Comment: I think there is no need to get success message if all required fields are input, of course it's possible but you should do validation at client not after submit action then return to the client the result of validation. To get email send success message, just add one more to your php code and response that if the server sending email done.

Comment: why the message persists if input form has been filled ? can you tell me some code @QuanNguyen

Comment: I'm thinking about qtip('destroy') statement. It works? If not, you can try to use 'hide' or 'remove' or you may want to loop for each qtip element and remove it. For example: jQuery( '#IdElement').qtip('destroy');

Comment: One more u can try: replace $('#contact-form-submit').qtip('destroy'); with $('.qtip').remove();

Comment: where i must add send mail function ?  and i want to showing success message if send mail is success. help me please, i dont understand with qtip and passing data  @QuanNguyen

Comment: I don't know much about PHP, but u can write code for sending email in your "contact-form.php". qtip just a plug in for the jQuery is used to display tooltip with several style u want. This is an example how to send email and cache status message with PHP: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_sending_emails.htm

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to grab a copyrighted template through preview. Support a developer by purchasing template - you will not only get a correct templating files, php plugins, but also technical support from developer himself.